# How to display SUM of visible cells in a userform label?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I would like to display the SUM of *visible* cells from column D in a Userform Label, and have it update automatically as the spreadsheet gets filtered.

I have this code

```vb
Private Sub SUM_click()
    Me.SUM.caption = range ("AA2")
End Sub
```

This is problematic.

- 1. I use a SUM formula in cell *AA2*.
     I’d like to avoid using formulas in any cells, if possible.
- 2. The return value isn’t excluding rows which are hidden.
- 3. It displays the value after I click on the label.
     I want it to display automatically.

Comment: [Subtotal Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60392&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: How do I incorporate that into VBA code for a userform label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Automate display of SubTotals in UserForm**

This reveals being not as trivial as it may seem.

Of course you *might* profit from a sheet's `Worksheet_Calculate` event
to get subtotals (of visible cells) by means of VBA whenever the (enabled) calculation processes a new result.
This is effective when filtering and/or when changing values, *whereas the `Worksheet_Change` event wouldn't cover filtering*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim subtotal As Double
    subtotal = Sheet1.Evaluate("=Subtotal(109,D:D)")     ' argument 109 sums up only visible cells!
    Debug.Print "Subtotal: " & Format(subtotal, "0.00")  ' display in VB Editor's immediate window
End Sub
```

> ... *but* there's no synchronized event to refresh a label in the Userform's code.

---

So I suggest the following **tricky workaround** profiting from the ListBox property `RowSource`:

- add the subtotal formula `=SUBTOTAL(109,D:D)` to cell `AA2`
- instead of a label ... let a listbox do the display binding it to a `.RowSource`; whenever a subtotal gets changed this will be reflected in the only list value of the bound listbox.

*Defining the appearance via `.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat` makes the Listbox appear nearly like a label. Small beauty mistake: the background color can't be modified*

**UserForm code example**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Me.ListBox1                ' << rename control to any other name
    .ColumnCount = 1            ' define columncount
    .ColumnWidths = .Width - 8  ' play around with small sizes to avoid scroll bars
    .Height = 12                
    .RowSource = "Sheet1!AA2"       ' reference to cell containing subtotal formula
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
    .ListIndex = 0          ' activate first (and only) record
End With
```

**Tip**

To enable concurrent actions like editing or filtering in the table, you need to show the UserForm **modeless**, e.g. via

```
    With New UserForm1
        .Show vbModeless
    End With
```

**Alternative suggested in comment**

Thx to @norie's hint, it would also be possible to profit from a textbox'es `.ControlSource` property (having more ressemblance to a label) without the need of further cosmetics. Nevertheless this promising approach needs further (or even more complicated?) steps: a textbox allows inputs which would *overwrite* the initial formula in the referred cell which isn't wanted.

Possible ways out I won't develop here: prevent key-event entries (have a look into other SO posts) or use the `TextBox1_Change` event to rewrite the formula each time the textbox got changed (doubtful), place a blocking control over the textbox etc.

Comment: T.M. Is there a reason you don't use a textbox and populate it using the ControlSource property?

Comment: @norie Thanks, of course this is a further possibility, though with caveats; will integrate your hint in my post :-)

Comment: Userform_initialize + subtotal formula in the cell worked perfectly, thank you. I was even able to change the background color of the listbox through the properties controls, so everything blended seamlessly into the userform box(: